# Using Google Geocoding Accuracy with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-geocoder

What is the syntax for accessing the Google Geocoding Accuracy value? This is what I currently have but it's a complete stab in the dark:

```
var googleValue = results[0].geomtery.Accuracy;
```

Comment: Looks like you are referring to the V2 version of the API, it is deprecated and **will stop working May 19, 2013**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comments says - V3 does not support this location feature anymore. Instead you receive a "location type" value which uses a four-tiered set of values to describe the accuracy. This can be accessed with the following syntax:

```
var googleValue = results[0].geometry.location_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index#GeocodingAccuracy) comes this example response:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=Toledo&output=json&sensor=false&gl=es
#
# Returns
#
{
  "name": "Toledo",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Toledo, Spain",
    "AddressDetails": {
        "Country": {
            "CountryNameCode": "ES",
            "CountryName": "Spain",
            "AdministrativeArea": {
                "AdministrativeAreaName": "CM",
                "SubAdministrativeArea":     {
                    "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "Toledo",
                    "Locality": {"LocalityName": "Toledo"}
                }
            }
        },
        "Accuracy": 4},
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -4.0244759, 39.8567775, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

So you would access it as `PlaceMark[0].AddressDetails.Accuracy`.